# Google Visualization Charts ajax data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to dynamically render a google visualization chart with an AJAX call in flask to set the data.  User enters input then clicks a link which calls the ajax function to get the data.  the "/ajax_test" view will return a json object but the problem I have is i don't know how to correctly pass the data back into the DataTable function.  How do i pass the json data i'm getting from ajax to a variable for the drawchart function?

Chart function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function drawChart(){
     var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsondata);
      var options = {
             explorer: {},
          }; //end options

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

Ajax function:

```
<script type=text/javascript>
$(function() {
$('a#DrawChart').bind('click', function() {
  $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/ajax_test',
   {//input data sent to view}
  , function(data) {
    var jsondata = data.test_json;
    drawChart();

  });
  return false;
   });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try changing `function drawChart() { ... }` to `function drawChart(jsondata) { ... }` and then in Ajax `drawChart(jsondata)` ?

Comment: I did not.  Now I did, and it works.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method doesn't know where `jsondata` comes from:

```
function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsondata);
    ...
}
```

Add `jsondata` as a parameter:

```
function drawChart(jsondata) {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsondata);
    ...
}
```

And then in your Ajax call pass `jsondata` to the method:

```
function(data) {
    var jsondata = data.test_json;
    drawChart(jsondata);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar using the following code, this is a jinja2 example, so you have do adapt your code (change the way jsonData var is initialized):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        //load the Google Visualization API and the chart
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['corechart']});

    google.setOnLoadCallback (createChart);

    var jsonData = {{ value_columns | tojson | safe }}

    function createChart() {
        var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
        //define options for visualization
        var options = {is3D: 'no', title: 'Some Title' };

        attachRedrawForTab(chart, dataTable, options);
        attachRedrawForAccord(chart, dataTable, options);
        //draw our chart
        chart.draw(dataTable, options);
    }

</script>
```